# Parse many numbers containing commas from string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a series of strings that all include 1 or many numbers (a number in this case would be 123,123,123) in the following format

```
"This is a number 123,124,123"
"These are some more numbers 123,345,123; 231,123,123; 124,152,123"
"This one is an odd situation 123,124,125; 123,123,123; more text"
```

What is the cleanest way to parse these numbers into either an array or a string that I can split that looks like this?

```
"123,124,123"
"123,345,123;231,123,123;124,152,123"
"123,124,125;123,123,123;"
```

Ultimately I want to be able to separate out the numbers like this.

```
"123,124,123"
"123,345,123" "231,123,123" "124,152,123"
"123,124,125" "123,123,123"
```

Currently attempting to use

```
"string".scan( /\d/ )
```

but obviously this is only giving me the numbers without the commas and also not separated properly.

Comment: I think you need to change 134 in the first line to 124.  No reply req'd as I'll delete this comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this

```
string.scan(/[\d,]+/)
```

Comment: Thanks Sawa. See my changes above. Ultimately I need the commas in the number because I need to use them in a 123,123,123 format in a query.

Comment: Note that this regex can match `,` or `35635656,,,,,,,,26543565625`

Comment: Thank you George. Fortunately for me it should not encounter situations like that.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to remove the unwanted characters.

```
arr = ["This is a number 123,124,123",
       "These are some more numbers 123,345,123; 231,123,123; 124,152,123",
       "This one is an odd situation 123,124,125; 123,123,123; more text"]

arr.map { |str| str.gsub(/[^\s\d,]+/,'').split }
  #=> [["123,124,123"],
  #    ["123,345,123", "231,123,123", "124,152,123"],
  #    ["123,124,125", "123,123,123"]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Regex that matches your numbers is `\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*`